# Issues with XML and C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to figure out this issue with XML and after a week I still can't figure it out and any help would be highly appreciated.

The task at hand:
I have a list view that is populated by data from the database based on the year parameter and it will select everyone that worked that year and fill listview with data.
Now I need to filter that data and sort it by people id (it can have one record or multiple records for the same year) and apply it to XML.
My code for now is:

```
const int Pozicija0 = 0;
        const int Pozicija1 = 1;
        const int Pozicija2 = 2;
        const int Pozicija3 = 3;
        const int Pozicija4 = 4;
        const int Pozicija5 = 5;
        const int Pozicija6 = 6;
        const int Pozicija7 = 7;
        const int Pozicija8 = 8;
        const int Pozicija9 = 9;
        const int Pozicija10 = 10;
        const int Pozicija11 = 11;
        const int Pozicija12 = 12;
        const int Pozicija13 = 13;
        const int Pozicija14 = 14;
        const int Pozicija15 = 15;
        const int Pozicija16 = 16;
        const int Pozicija17 = 17;
        const int Pozicija18 = 18;


        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode root = doc.CreateElement("PaketniUvozObrazaca");
        XmlAttribute att = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns");
        att.Value = "urn:PaketniUvozObrazaca_V1_0.xsd";
        root.Attributes.Append(att);
        doc.AppendChild(root);
        XmlNode podaciposlodavac = doc.CreateElement("PodaciOPoslodavcu");
        root.AppendChild(podaciposlodavac);
        XmlNode jib = doc.CreateElement("JIBPoslodavca");
        jib.InnerText = this.label7.Text;
        podaciposlodavac.AppendChild(jib);
        XmlNode Naziv = doc.CreateElement("NazivPoslodavca");
        Naziv.InnerText = this.label9.Text;
        podaciposlodavac.AppendChild(Naziv);
        XmlNode brojzahtjeva = doc.CreateElement("BrojZahtjeva");
        brojzahtjeva.InnerText = this.label4.Text;
        podaciposlodavac.AppendChild(brojzahtjeva);
        XmlNode datump = doc.CreateElement("DatumPodnosenja");
        datump.InnerText = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        podaciposlodavac.AppendChild(datump);


        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            string Item1 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija1].Text;
            string Item2 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija2].Text;


            XmlNode obrazac1022 = doc.CreateElement("Obrazac1022");
            root.AppendChild(obrazac1022);
            XmlNode dio1 = doc.CreateElement("Dio1PodaciOPoslodavcuIPoreznomObvezniku");
            obrazac1022.AppendChild(dio1);
            XmlNode jib2 = doc.CreateElement("JIBJMBPoslodavca");
            jib2.InnerText = this.label7.Text;
            dio1.AppendChild(jib2);
            XmlNode Naziv2 = doc.CreateElement("Naziv");
            Naziv2.InnerText = this.label9.Text;
            dio1.AppendChild(Naziv2);
            XmlNode Adresa = doc.CreateElement("AdresaSjedista");
            Adresa.InnerText = this.label11.Text;
            dio1.AppendChild(Adresa);
            XmlNode JMB = doc.CreateElement("JMBZaposlenika");
            JMB.InnerText = Item1;
            dio1.AppendChild(JMB);
            XmlNode ime = doc.CreateElement("ImeIPrezime");
            ime.InnerText = Item2;
            dio1.AppendChild(ime);
            XmlNode adresa = doc.CreateElement("AdresaPrebivalista");
            adresa.InnerText = "Stjepan Polje bb";
            dio1.AppendChild(adresa);
            XmlNode poreznagodina = doc.CreateElement("PoreznaGodina");
            poreznagodina.InnerText = txtPoslovnaGodina.Text;
            dio1.AppendChild(poreznagodina);

            foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.listView1.Items)
            {
                string Item0 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija0].Text;
                string Item3 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija3].Text;
                string Item4 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija4].Text;
                string Item5 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija5].Text;
                string Item6 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija6].Text;
                string Item8 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija8].Text;
                string Item9 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija9].Text;
                string Item10 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija10].Text;
                string Item12 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija12].Text;
                string Item13 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija13].Text;
                string Item14 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija14].Text;
                string Item15 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija15].Text;
                string Item16 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija16].Text;
                string Item17 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija17].Text;

                DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Item17);
                string a = Convert.ToString(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                decimal d3 = decimal.Parse(Item5);
                string bplaca = Convert.ToString(d3.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d4 = decimal.Parse(Item6);
                string BSU = Convert.ToString(d4.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d5 = d3 + d4;
                string Brutozbir = Convert.ToString(d5.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d6 = decimal.Parse(Item8);
                string PIO = Convert.ToString(d6.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d7 = decimal.Parse(Item9);
                string ZZO = Convert.ToString(d7.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d8 = decimal.Parse(Item10);
                string OON = Convert.ToString(d8.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d9 = d6 + d7 + d8;
                string UDoprisnos = Convert.ToString(d9.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d10 = d5 - d9;
                string PBDopr = Convert.ToString(d10.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d11 = decimal.Parse(Item12);
                string Flic = Convert.ToString(d11.ToString("0.000", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d12 = decimal.Parse(Item13);
                string IznsoLO = Convert.ToString(d12.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d13 = decimal.Parse(Item14);
                string OsnovicaP = Convert.ToString(d13.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d14 = decimal.Parse(Item15);
                string IznosPO = Convert.ToString(d14.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d15 = decimal.Parse(Item16);
                string NetoP = Convert.ToString(d15.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));

                XmlNode dio2 = doc.CreateElement("Dio2PodaciOPrihodimaDoprinosimaIPorezu");
                obrazac1022.AppendChild(dio2);
                XmlNode prihodiporezi = doc.CreateElement("PodaciOPrihodimaDoprinosimaIPorezu");
                dio2.AppendChild(prihodiporezi);
                XmlNode mjesec = doc.CreateElement("Mjesec");
                mjesec.InnerText = Item0;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(mjesec);
                XmlNode mjesei = doc.CreateElement("IsplataZaMjesecIGodinu");
                mjesei.InnerText = Item3;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(mjesei);
                XmlNode vrstaisplate = doc.CreateElement("VrstaIsplate");
                vrstaisplate.InnerText = Item4;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(vrstaisplate);
                XmlNode brutoplata = doc.CreateElement("IznosPrihodaUNovcu");
                brutoplata.InnerText = bplaca;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(brutoplata);
                XmlNode stvariusluge = doc.CreateElement("IznosPrihodaUStvarimaUslugama");
                stvariusluge.InnerText = BSU;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(stvariusluge);
                XmlNode UBruto = doc.CreateElement("BrutoPlaca");
                UBruto.InnerText = Brutozbir;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(UBruto);
                XmlNode iznosPIO = doc.CreateElement("IznosZaPenzijskoInvalidskoOsiguranje");
                iznosPIO.InnerText = PIO;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(iznosPIO);
                XmlNode iznosZO = doc.CreateElement("IznosZaZdravstvenoOsiguranje");
                iznosZO.InnerText = ZZO;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(iznosZO);
                XmlNode iznosOON = doc.CreateElement("IznosZaOsiguranjeOdNezaposlenosti");
                iznosOON.InnerText = OON;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(iznosOON);
                XmlNode UDoprinosi2 = doc.CreateElement("UkupniDoprinosi");
                UDoprinosi2.InnerText = UDoprisnos;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(UDoprinosi2);
                XmlNode platebdop = doc.CreateElement("PlacaBezDoprinosa");
                platebdop.InnerText = PBDopr;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(platebdop);
                XmlNode Flicnogodbitka = doc.CreateElement("FaktorLicnihOdbitakaPremaPoreznojKartici");
                Flicnogodbitka.InnerText = Flic;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(Flicnogodbitka);
                XmlNode IznosLicnogO = doc.CreateElement("IznosLicnogOdbitka");
                IznosLicnogO.InnerText = IznsoLO;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(IznosLicnogO);
                XmlNode OsnovicaPoreza = doc.CreateElement("OsnovicaPoreza");
                OsnovicaPoreza.InnerText = OsnovicaP;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(OsnovicaPoreza);
                XmlNode IznosUplacenogPoreza = doc.CreateElement("IznosUplacenogPoreza");
                IznosUplacenogPoreza.InnerText = IznosPO;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(IznosUplacenogPoreza);
                XmlNode Netoplate = doc.CreateElement("NetoPlaca");
                Netoplate.InnerText = NetoP;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(Netoplate);
                XmlNode datumuplate = doc.CreateElement("DatumUplate");
                datumuplate.InnerText = a;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(datumuplate);
                XmlNode ukupno = doc.CreateElement("Ukupno");
                dio2.AppendChild(ukupno);

                double valorSum = 0;
                double sum1 = 0;
                double sum2 = 0;
                double sum3 = 0;
                double sum4 = 0;
                double sum5 = 0;
                double sum6 = 0;
                double sum7 = 0;
                double sum8 = 0;

                foreach (ListViewItem lstItem in listView1.Items)
                {
                    valorSum += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[5].Text);
                    sum1 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[6].Text);
                    sum2 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[8].Text);
                    sum3 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[9].Text);
                    sum4 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[10].Text);
                    sum5 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[13].Text);
                    sum6 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[14].Text);
                    sum7 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[15].Text);
                    sum8 += double.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[16].Text);
                }
                string nz = Convert.ToString(valorSum.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string bus = Convert.ToString(sum1.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                double g;
                g = valorSum + sum1;
                string platabruto = Convert.ToString(g.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string pioukupno = Convert.ToString(sum2.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string zzoukupno = Convert.ToString(sum3.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string oonukupno = Convert.ToString(sum4.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                double b;
                b = sum2 + sum3 + sum4;
                string uudop = Convert.ToString(b.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                double c;
                c = g - b;
                string bezdop = Convert.ToString(c.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string sumLO = Convert.ToString(sum5.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string sumPO = Convert.ToString(sum6.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string sumUP = Convert.ToString(sum7.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                string sumNP = Convert.ToString(sum8.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));

                XmlNode iznosPN = doc.CreateElement("IznosPrihodaUNovcu");
                iznosPN.InnerText = nz;
                ukupno.AppendChild(iznosPN);
                XmlNode iznosBSU = doc.CreateElement("IznosPrihodaUStvarimaUslugama");
                iznosBSU.InnerText = bus;
                ukupno.AppendChild(iznosBSU);
                XmlNode iznosbrut = doc.CreateElement("BrutoPlaca");
                iznosbrut.InnerText = platabruto;
                ukupno.AppendChild(iznosbrut);
                XmlNode iznosPOo = doc.CreateElement("IznosZaPenzijskoInvalidskoOsiguranje");
                iznosPOo.InnerText = pioukupno;
                ukupno.AppendChild(iznosPOo);
                XmlNode iznoszooo = doc.CreateElement("IznosZaZdravstvenoOsiguranje");
                iznoszooo.InnerText = zzoukupno;
                ukupno.AppendChild(iznoszooo);
                XmlNode iznosooon = doc.CreateElement("IznosZaOsiguranjeOdNezaposlenosti");
                iznosooon.InnerText = oonukupno;
                ukupno.AppendChild(iznosooon);
                XmlNode doprinosoou = doc.CreateElement("UkupniDoprinosi");
                doprinosoou.InnerText = uudop;
                ukupno.AppendChild(doprinosoou);
                XmlNode platebezdoprinosa = doc.CreateElement("PlacaBezDoprinosa");
                platebezdoprinosa.InnerText = bezdop;
                ukupno.AppendChild(platebezdoprinosa);
                XmlNode sumalicnogo = doc.CreateElement("IznosLicnogOdbitka");
                sumalicnogo.InnerText = sumLO;
                ukupno.AppendChild(sumalicnogo);
                XmlNode sumaporeza = doc.CreateElement("OsnovicaPoreza");
                sumaporeza.InnerText = sumPO;
                ukupno.AppendChild(sumaporeza);
                XmlNode sumauplporeza = doc.CreateElement("IznosUplacenogPoreza");
                sumauplporeza.InnerText = sumUP;
                ukupno.AppendChild(sumauplporeza);
                XmlNode sumanetopl = doc.CreateElement("NetoPlaca");
                sumanetopl.InnerText = sumNP;
                ukupno.AppendChild(sumanetopl);
                XmlNode dio3 = doc.CreateElement("Dio3IzjavaPoslodavcaIsplatioca");
                obrazac1022.AppendChild(dio3);
                XmlNode poslodavaca = doc.CreateElement("JIBJMBPoslodavca");
                poslodavaca.InnerText = label7.Text;
                dio3.AppendChild(poslodavaca);
                XmlNode datumunosa = doc.CreateElement("DatumUnosa");
                datumunosa.InnerText = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                dio3.AppendChild(datumunosa);
                XmlNode kompanija = doc.CreateElement("NazivPoslodavca");
                kompanija.InnerText = label9.Text;
                dio3.AppendChild(kompanija);
                XmlNode dokument = doc.CreateElement("Dokument");
                obrazac1022.AppendChild(dokument);
                XmlNode operacija = doc.CreateElement("Operacija");
                operacija.InnerText = "Novi";
                dokument.AppendChild(operacija);
            }
        }
```

I have a problem with the following part of the code:

```
foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in this.listView1.Items)
            {
                string Item0 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija0].Text;
                string Item3 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija3].Text;
                string Item4 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija4].Text;
                string Item5 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija5].Text;
                string Item6 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija6].Text;
                string Item8 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija8].Text;
                string Item9 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija9].Text;
                string Item10 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija10].Text;
                string Item12 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija12].Text;
                string Item13 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija13].Text;
                string Item14 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija14].Text;
                string Item15 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija15].Text;
                string Item16 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija16].Text;
                string Item17 = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[Pozicija17].Text;

                DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Item17);
                string a = Convert.ToString(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                decimal d3 = decimal.Parse(Item5);
                string bplaca = Convert.ToString(d3.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d4 = decimal.Parse(Item6);
                string BSU = Convert.ToString(d4.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d5 = d3 + d4;
                string Brutozbir = Convert.ToString(d5.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d6 = decimal.Parse(Item8);
                string PIO = Convert.ToString(d6.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d7 = decimal.Parse(Item9);
                string ZZO = Convert.ToString(d7.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d8 = decimal.Parse(Item10);
                string OON = Convert.ToString(d8.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d9 = d6 + d7 + d8;
                string UDoprisnos = Convert.ToString(d9.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d10 = d5 - d9;
                string PBDopr = Convert.ToString(d10.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d11 = decimal.Parse(Item12);
                string Flic = Convert.ToString(d11.ToString("0.000", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d12 = decimal.Parse(Item13);
                string IznsoLO = Convert.ToString(d12.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d13 = decimal.Parse(Item14);
                string OsnovicaP = Convert.ToString(d13.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d14 = decimal.Parse(Item15);
                string IznosPO = Convert.ToString(d14.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
                decimal d15 = decimal.Parse(Item16);
                string NetoP = Convert.ToString(d15.ToString("0.00", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));

                XmlNode dio2 = doc.CreateElement("Dio2PodaciOPrihodimaDoprinosimaIPorezu");
                obrazac1022.AppendChild(dio2);
                XmlNode prihodiporezi = doc.CreateElement("PodaciOPrihodimaDoprinosimaIPorezu");
                dio2.AppendChild(prihodiporezi);
                XmlNode mjesec = doc.CreateElement("Mjesec");
                mjesec.InnerText = Item0;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(mjesec);
                XmlNode mjesei = doc.CreateElement("IsplataZaMjesecIGodinu");
                mjesei.InnerText = Item3;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(mjesei);
                XmlNode vrstaisplate = doc.CreateElement("VrstaIsplate");
                vrstaisplate.InnerText = Item4;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(vrstaisplate);
                XmlNode brutoplata = doc.CreateElement("IznosPrihodaUNovcu");
                brutoplata.InnerText = bplaca;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(brutoplata);
                XmlNode stvariusluge = doc.CreateElement("IznosPrihodaUStvarimaUslugama");
                stvariusluge.InnerText = BSU;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(stvariusluge);
                XmlNode UBruto = doc.CreateElement("BrutoPlaca");
                UBruto.InnerText = Brutozbir;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(UBruto);
                XmlNode iznosPIO = doc.CreateElement("IznosZaPenzijskoInvalidskoOsiguranje");
                iznosPIO.InnerText = PIO;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(iznosPIO);
                XmlNode iznosZO = doc.CreateElement("IznosZaZdravstvenoOsiguranje");
                iznosZO.InnerText = ZZO;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(iznosZO);
                XmlNode iznosOON = doc.CreateElement("IznosZaOsiguranjeOdNezaposlenosti");
                iznosOON.InnerText = OON;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(iznosOON);
                XmlNode UDoprinosi2 = doc.CreateElement("UkupniDoprinosi");
                UDoprinosi2.InnerText = UDoprisnos;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(UDoprinosi2);
                XmlNode platebdop = doc.CreateElement("PlacaBezDoprinosa");
                platebdop.InnerText = PBDopr;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(platebdop);
                XmlNode Flicnogodbitka = doc.CreateElement("FaktorLicnihOdbitakaPremaPoreznojKartici");
                Flicnogodbitka.InnerText = Flic;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(Flicnogodbitka);
                XmlNode IznosLicnogO = doc.CreateElement("IznosLicnogOdbitka");
                IznosLicnogO.InnerText = IznsoLO;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(IznosLicnogO);
                XmlNode OsnovicaPoreza = doc.CreateElement("OsnovicaPoreza");
                OsnovicaPoreza.InnerText = OsnovicaP;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(OsnovicaPoreza);
                XmlNode IznosUplacenogPoreza = doc.CreateElement("IznosUplacenogPoreza");
                IznosUplacenogPoreza.InnerText = IznosPO;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(IznosUplacenogPoreza);
                XmlNode Netoplate = doc.CreateElement("NetoPlaca");
                Netoplate.InnerText = NetoP;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(Netoplate);
                XmlNode datumuplate = doc.CreateElement("DatumUplate");
                datumuplate.InnerText = a;
                prihodiporezi.AppendChild(datumuplate);
                XmlNode ukupno = doc.CreateElement("Ukupno");
                dio2.AppendChild(ukupno);
```

Predefined XML structure looks like this:

```html
<xs:complexType name="type_PrihodiPoreziDoprinosi">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Mjesec" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="IsplataZaMjesecIGodinu" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="VrstaIsplate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="IznosPrihodaUNovcu" type="type_Money" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="IznosPrihodaUStvarimaUslugama" type="type_Money" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="BrutoPlaca" type="type_Money" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="IznosZaPenzijskoInvalidskoOsiguranje" type="type_Money" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="IznosZaZdravstvenoOsiguranje" type="type_Money" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="IznosZaOsiguranjeOdNezaposlenosti" type="type_Money" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="UkupniDoprinosi" type="type_Money" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="PlacaBezDoprinosa" type="type_Money" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="FaktorLicnihOdbitakaPremaPoreznojKartici" type="type_Koeficijent" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="IznosLicnogOdbitka" type="type_Money" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="OsnovicaPoreza" type="type_Money" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="IznosUplacenogPoreza" type="type_Money" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="NetoPlaca" type="type_Money" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="DatumUplate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And I need to loop through data and apply it same Node before moving to another and doing the same.

Any help or guidance is appreciated since I'm stuck and can't figure it out for some reason.

Comment: Lots of code. It is much better to start using **LINQ to XML** API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

Comment: Unrelated: Why do you keep converting to string, what is already a string?

Comment: ^^ Related: Why don't you work on an object model, that is serialized/deserialized to/from XML ?

Comment: It is a lot of code, I've tried LINQ and got stuck, even more, couldn't figure out how to loop through list view, if there is a suggestion on how to loop I appreciate it and will try it.